# How to increase length of whiskers of "standard, static" crosshair?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I prefer the "standard, static" crosshair but would like it to have longer whiskers. How can I achieve this?

I think I was not able to change it with the crosshair commands I found, such as **sixense_crosshair_horiz_multiplier "1"** and
**sixense_crosshair_vert_multiplier "1"** The most important aspect of it I was not able to reproduce with custom crosshair settings is that the inner part of it appears dark on very bright backgrounds while the outer whiskers appear bright on dark backgrounds so it is visible in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.krisskarbo.com/csgocrosshair/

This is a crosshair generator. Tweak whatever you need and then save the Config it gives you. Pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Although this is a very nice website, it does not directly answer my question, since it is not clear how to produce the two-colored crosshair I describe and change its size. If that is possible with the settings used in the site, please explain.

Comment: @Konsta The site shows you all of the settings as you change them: cl_crosshairsize "x" and I suggest just using pink. I'm not sure if multicolored is possible.

Comment: Well, just check out the "standard, static" crosshair. It has an inner crosshair with one color and an outer one with another. If I do not get another answer in a couple of days I'll accept yours since it is stll a very good way of customising a crosshair.

Answer (score 1):

> cl_crosshairsize

Play around with the numbers to figure out what size works for you. I typically prefer a small crosshair and use 2. If you want longer, you should try something like 5 or 6.

You can also adjust the gap in between the crosshair if you don't like how spread out or close together they are with the following (I like it close with -2)

> cl_crosshairgap