# How can I make a really static crosshair in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When I watch some CS:GO videos, I see they have fully static crosshair. For example, in this video,  [NiP vs eXtensive from ESL Major Series Winter 2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=bZ2Y4O-PYSw#t=585s). I'm not talking about a recoil control thing. I mean that guys in the video can smoothly pull their aim down. However, when I shoot there is a little vibration on my crosshair. I mean very small, left and right. How do they do that?

edit: I painted : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljryk.png
compare this videos 
first:

(sorry 4 the quality, fraps gives me too big file when I choose better resol)
second one:

Comment: Having not have watched the video, just generally speaking for any FPS. The best way to manage your crosshair and recoil is to shoot in bursts.

Comment: My guess is a stable mouse. TRy a better surface for your existing mouse (a good mousepad) or a good high resolution gaming mouse. Seems like what you are experiencing is mouse tremors.

Comment: Tape a red dot to your screen!

Comment: Crosshair and recoil are different things, guys... He's asking about the crosshair.

Comment: @emerica I dont want to burst , retrosaur; I dont understand

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96508/how-to-increase-length-of-whiskers-of-standard-static-crosshair

Comment: I dont think it is related. going to upload a video in 10min :(

Comment: So you're saying when your hand is still, your crosshair moves around a bit?

Comment: @emmett There's no tricks happening here, they're just good at controlling their recoil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get rid of these little shakes when you shoot and aim down to compensate the recoil. It's only possible, when you're using "sv_cheats 1", so it won't be possible in any server. The NiP aim is not smooth as you think. It just looks like it's smooth, because you're a GOTV spectator. On GOTV they turned off this visual shakes, to make it more watchable for a general public. Try, instead, to get used to that. The shakes appears to annoy a little less when you play at 128 tick rate servers. Try that too. Good luck and keep practicing.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you ever wanted to know about CS:GO crosshairs: http://www.pro-hl.com/columns/csgo_crosshairs.php

The part in particular you are looking for is at the bottom of the page.

> These crosshairs may not indicate friendly & enemy targets but does
>   allow you to change your crosshair colour and restore that CS look as
>   seen in CS:S & CS1.6. You can also change the thickness of the
>   crosshair by using cl_crosshairthickness "1", add a centre dot (as
>   seen above) by using cl_crosshairdot "1", change the crosshairs to red
>   by cl_crosshaircolor_r "250", **make them static by cl_crosshairstyle
>   "2"& cl_observercrosshair "1"**

Comment: I dont think this is about crosshair settings, and btw it is already cl_crosshairstyle "2"& cl_observercrosshair "1"

Comment: You might try rephrasing the question, it's a bit confusing.

Comment: I edited the question. I guess @Samyam A is maybe right

Comment: I suggest reading over this mouse optimization guide. Some things in the document no longer apply, but there is plenty of relevant configuration information. http://www.overclock.net/t/173255/cs-s-mouse-optimization-guide Also check out fatal1ty's guide: http://fatal1ty.com/fatal1ty-mouse-sensitivity/

Answer (score 0):

If you make a dot crosshair it's completely static. Like this:

```
cl_crosshairalpha "200";
cl_crosshaircolor "5";
cl_crosshaircolor_b "0";
cl_crosshaircolor_r "0";
cl_crosshaircolor_g "255";
cl_crosshairdot "1";
cl_crosshairgap "0";
cl_crosshairsize "0";
cl_crosshairstyle "2";
cl_crosshairusealpha "1";
cl_crosshairthickness "1.5";
cl_fixedcrosshairgap "0";
cl_crosshair_outline "0";
cl_crosshair_outline_draw "0";
```